# how to group items and convert to list in java

Tags: java, list, group-by, dto

I have DTO like following

```
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String fullName;
    private String phone;
    private String role;
    private List<String> roleList;

    public UserDTO(String id, List<String> roleList) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.roleList = roleList;
    }
}
```

I have the list of `UserDTO` where `roleList` is not populated but `role` is populated. The problem is `role` could be multiple but somehow i can't manage to get the list in a single query. So, I want to group by id and generate `roleList`.

For example, I have the following rows:

```
id     fullName     phone     role     roleList
------------------------------------------------
abc    Sarwar       017xxx    admin    NULL
abc    Sarwar       017xxx    operator NULL

I want it to be like the following 

abc    Sarwar       017xxx    NULL      ArrayList<String>(admin, operator)
```

I have tried the following but it is not working (shouldn't though but i can't figure out what it should be) that's why i am seeking your help:

```
Map<String, List<UserDTO>> resultsWithSameIdAndName = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getId()));

List<UserDTO> mergedResults = resultsWithSameIdAndName.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new UserDTO(e.getKey(), 
                e.getValue().stream().map(r -> r.getRole()).collect(Collectors.toList())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be a design issue with your model. What does `role` field mean after `roleList` is populated?

Comment: Can you mention what is not working? What output is your code producing for the example you've given?

Comment: @user7: actually this is not the entity this an intermediate model which serves as DTO. I can't populate list of role from hibernate. actually, my tried code is not populating roleList. It is `NULL` as previous. I want it to be a `List`

Comment: Are you looking at the new `mergedResults` object? or the `users` object?

Comment: @user7: `mergedResults` actually. in fact `mergedResults` is a list of `UserDTO` but mergedResults is not working. I want to group with `id` and populate `roleList`. This is my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: You are grouping it correctly. The UserDTO created by `new UserDTO(..)` should have the correct roleList (unless there is a problem within the constructor. Also, you are not populating other fields (like `phone`).

Comment: @user7: thnx again. but the problem is role is populated not the roleList. This line `r -> r.getRole()` is not populating `roleList`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the constructor of UserDTO - to know what is being done with the second parameter. Are you assigning it to roleList?

Comment: @user7: constructor added

Comment: I do not see any issue with your code except that you are not populating fullName and phone fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. I added another way to this.

First prepare map for `roleList` by user `id`

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultsWithSameIdAndName = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserDTO::getId,
                 Collectors.mapping(d-> d.getRole(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Then create unique user list by user `id`

```
List<UserDTO> uniqueUsers = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(UserDTO::getId))),ArrayList::new));
```

And get role list from map and set for every user

```
for(UserDTO user :uniqueUsers) {
    user.setRoleList(resultsWithSameIdAndName.get(user.getId()));
}
```

Comment: I found this error "The method toCollection(() -> {}) is undefined for the type UserDaoImpl"

Comment: I updated `unique user list prepare part`,check now,  there is a problem is `Comparator` function

Comment: Still i found the same error ... i think, it may be some syntax error!! "The method toCollection(() -> {}) is undefined"

Comment: Maybe you don't staticly import `toCollection`. Updated

Comment: Here I added full working code https://onlinegdb.com/BJOss-VqU , the interesting fact is your code also working, also  added with my  code

Comment: Did you check ?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserDTO  {
    private String id;
    private String fullName;
    private String phone;
    private String role;
    private List<String> roleList;

    public UserDTO(String id,String fullName,String phone,String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.role =role;
    }

    public UserDTO(UserDTO oldObject,String key, List<String> collect) {
        this.id = key;
        this.fullName = oldObject.getFullName();
        this.phone = oldObject.getPhone();
        this.roleList = collect;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public List<String> getRoleList() {
        return roleList;
    }

    public void setRoleList(List<String> roleList) {
        this.roleList = roleList;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<UserDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new UserDTO("ASD", "John", "12345", "user"));
        list.add(new UserDTO("ASD", "John", "12345", "admin"));
        list.add(new UserDTO("SDB", "Smith", "12345", "super user"));
        list.add(new UserDTO("SDB", "Smith", "12345", "admin"));
        list.add(new UserDTO("DFG", "Neo", "12345", "user"));
        Map<String, List<UserDTO>> resultsWithSameIdAndName = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserDTO::getId));
        List<UserDTO> mergedResults = resultsWithSameIdAndName.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new UserDTO(
                        e.getValue().get(0),
                        e.getKey(),
                        e.getValue().stream().map(UserDTO::getRole).collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(mergedResults);

    }

}
```

Only changes that I done is added a parameter in constructor which takes an `UserDTO` object.